# react-native: how to update to build tools 23.0.2?

Tags: react-native, build-tools

When build production, signed, apk, I noticed these rows in the output:

```
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
```

I (think to) remember that it's mandatory to have android build-tools at exact version 23.0.1.

What must I do to update the project ?

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled build-tools 23.0.1 and installed 23.0.3.

Then I updated `build.gradle` file as suggested from sfratini, but I got this when building:

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in C:\Users\realtebo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses 
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 accepted. 
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1".
```

Of course, the suggestion to use lastest build-tool is disappeared, but I cannot understand why the old build-tool is automatically forcely installed.

Comment: Have you got any other projects in android studio from other 3rd party packages like react-native-vector-icons? They might still point to build tools 23.0.1 by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am actually using 23.0.3 with no issues so far. Just update your gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

If you put your cursor over the version, AS might even prompt you to update the version.

Comment: I changed build,gradle as you suggested, but at next run of gradlew It redownloaded and reinstalled the 23.0.1.

Comment: `Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 in C:\Users\realtebo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1".
`

Comment: @realtebo Another component or module might have it as a requirement. Find all the other gradle files and check if some module is requiring that specific version.